# CacheInstaller.exe has stopped working

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2, azure, azure-web-roles, azure-caching

I am having below mentioned issue when I am running Asp.Net MVC 2 project on windows Azure emulator (dev environment)

I have installed **Windows Azure SDK for .NET - October 2012** version and I am using **cache feature** on my system.

[image]

With above error Below one is also comming.

[image]

How to get rid of this ?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe I have an stupid solution, but that works with me.

When I begin to recieve the message "CacheInstaller.exe has stopped working", I do the following:
1) Stop the execution.
2) Go to the Role I'm using in the Azure project and open the corresponding Properties page.
3) Go to the "Caching" section and there I uncheck the "Enable Caching" checkbox. After that I checked again. 
4) Save*, Run de application and never the warning appear again.

- Is weird because nothing should change if you uncheck and check it again an option without save in the middle, but in this case when you do that the file changes (I can see it in the red icon that said something change there, :P)

I hope this helps. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any error messages in the event log that may give more hint.
It could be an issue with missing dlls, do you have the windows server appFabric installed as well on this machine, which may be leading to a conflict with the dlls?
A procmon log might help you see what file paths its looking for.
"http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645"

Answer (score 1):

I banged my head against the wall on this one as well.  I finally figured out the problem after digging deep into the crash-dump logs located within: `C:\Users\{YOU}\AppData\Local\dftmp\Resources\{GUID}\directory\DiagnosticStore\AzureCaching\`

- `AzureCaching` does not allow UNC paths.

As my primary .net dev is from a vm, my documents/projects drive is mapped to my native drive located at: `\\psf\Home\Documents\...`  Once I moved the project to the vm `c:/ drive, CacheInstaller` worked as intended.

Might as well post my experience as I was unable to locate anything on this specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

I found today that if my system time was more than about 10 minutes wrong then CacheInstaller.exe bailed out on starting the emulator.

That includes the combination of system time and timezone being wrong, presumably as it results in an inability to calculate the correct UTC time at which Azure operates. Fixing the system clock resolved the issue in my case.