# CacheInstaller.exe wont start with Azure Emulator

Tags: windows, visual-studio, caching, azure

Yesterday my Azure emulator starting playing up and I've no idea why.  I've not changed anything in the setup etc so it is quite strange.

When I run the project the emulator wont start and eventually it tells me that CacheInstaller.exe wont start.

I tried running the CacheInstaller.exe on it's own and this is what I get.

[error http://lettingweb.com/img/email/capture.png](http://lettingweb.com/img/email/capture.png)

Does anyone have any idea what the issue could be, the error doesn't seem very clear to me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hmm...so if I disable caching and re-enable with the development storage it works fine however with my storage account details it wont work.

My internet is being strange today, could this error be caused if the emulator couldn't get out to my storage account?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CacheInstaller.exe has stopped working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14377774/cacheinstaller-exe-has-stopped-working)